# Accidentally uninstalled gnome 38, software center wont open

Tags: gnome, software-center, uninstall

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Hey there. I was just browsing through my ubuntu software center and uninstall and accidentally clicked the wrong thing, and uninstalled "gnome-38 *something*". everything seems to work fine, but the software center closed, and wont open again even after restart.
I tried `sudo apt install gnome-software` and a new app appeared in the dashboard:
[image]

It has missing textures, and is not the ubuntu software we know and love.

How can I fix this? (optimally without reinstalling my system xD)

Comment: You say Ubuntu 22.04 but that is not where this screen shot comes from. It looks like it comes from Kubuntu. If it was truly Ubuntu 22.04 it would be a Gnome 4.x flavor. Not sure how the screen shot helps the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely removed the `gnome-3-38-2004` snap.

If you run `snap changes` you may see it in the recent past, being removed. Also `snap info gnome-3-38-2004` will show it as not installed.

To reinstall:

`sudo snap install gnome-3-38-2004`

This should resolve the issue.